# Number portability across Google Voice

Tags: google-voice

My younger brother in-law wanted something like what Google Voice offers, so I gave him my GV number a few months ago to "try out" and see if he liked it.

He's shared the number with all his friends *and* put the number on his business card, and now I get calls all day long, even on weekends.

The GV number I have, that he uses, is something I rarely use, and would be happy to part with.

Is there a way by which I can "port" ( move ) my current GV number to be my brother in law's GV number ( he does not have a GV number yet ), and get myself a new number?

Alternately, would it be possible to swap GV numbers between two users? ( Assume he got 123-456-7890 and swapped that one with the one I have? )

At the worst, can I get a completely new number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Request to allow Google Voice transfer form](http://support.google.com/voice/bin/static.py?hl=en&ts=1378507&page=ts.cs&from=1378507&rd=2)

Use this form to request your Google Voice number be transferred from one Google Account to another (e.g. onetwothree@gmail.com to fourfivesix@gmail.com).

> Please follow the instructions EXACTLY AS THEY APPEAR, because if you do not enter your information correctly, it could result in wrongfully deleting all of your subscriber information, like your call history, text messages, and voicemails, for which Google cannot be responsible and which will be irreversible.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should be able to change your number, [like this](http://www.google.com/support/voice/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115114), but there's a $10 fee. If you contact their support, perhaps they can arrange for you to "swap" the numbers the way you want. I don't think there's a way to do this yourself, without contact customer service.

As an alternative solution, I would suggest checking out [Skype](http://www.skype.com/). I believe they offer the same kind of services with a bit more "flexibility" and with some additional features.